# Show that $h_n(x)=x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}$ converges uniformly on $[-1, 1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

This is a question about the uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

First, note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}h_n=|x|$ is known already. We simply need to get an appropriate bound on $|h_n(x)-h(x)|$.

Here's my attempt (note crucially that the domain is $[-1, 1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$):

$$
|h_n(x)-h(x)|=|x^{1+\frac{1}{2n-1}}-|x||=|x\cdot x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}-|x||\leq|x||x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}|+|x|=(|x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}|+1)|x|\leq |x^{\frac{1}{2n-1}}|+1\leq2.
$$

which obviously isn't helpful because the final expression does not involve $n$. In other words, I can't choose $n$ in response to some $\epsilon$-bound on the error $|h_n(x)-h(x)|$.

What are the required modifications? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be better if you compute $\max_{[0,1]}|x^{1+1/(2n-1)}-x|$ Observe that since $h_n(x)$ and $|x|$ are even, you can concentrate on $[0,1]$ instead of $[-1,1]$

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that $h_n(x) \to x$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ since $h_n$ is even. Let $\epsilon >0$ and note that $|h_n(x)-x| \leq |x||x^{\frac 1  {2n-1} }-1|\leq 2x<\epsilon $ if $x <\frac {\epsilon} 2$. Now let $x \geq \frac {\epsilon} 2$. Then $|h_n(x)-x| \leq |x^{\frac 1  {2n-1} }-1|=|e^{\frac 1  {2n-1} \ln x }-1|$. So $|h_n(x)-1| \leq e^{t_n} \frac 1 {2n-1} |\ln x|$ for some $t_n$ between $0$ and $\frac  1{2n-1} \ln x$ by MVT applied to the exponential function and observe that $\ln x$ is bounded for $\geq \frac {\epsilon} 2$. Can you finish the proof?